Deliver automatically Maximo package and configuration
Delivering a package and configuration on IBM Maximo can make deployment difficult, because the settings are done manually.
To make deployment easier and only deliver certain fields rather than all, I would like to automate this process. In terms of configuration, I would like to only deliver certain fields and not all of them each time.
It's not easy to understand how packages are generated, which would require reverse engineering.
Do you think this is possible and if so how ?
Thanks for answer
packages are zip files that contain xml files. These files are deployed in Maximo via its UI. This takes care of the configuration in BDD.
I think it would be possible to be able to automatically generate these packages by only selecting the fields that I want to deploy but not through the administration interface
